# How can I keep <div>'s and tables in their place when the browser window is shrunk?

Tags: html, css

I am a step shy of completing an `HTML` template for a basic web site and need a little advice.

My page's body is composed of `<div> tags`, all visually stacked on top of one another on the page. I only have one `<div>` with a child `<div>` but the rest have tables nested in them.
The tables are holding my content. I am Using the `<div>'s` for structure and alignment.

I just want all content to stay the same width and height when the browser is re-sized. I do not wish to have scroll bars or autohide.

I want the content to keep the same physical attributes and when the browser is shrunk, the scroll bar can appear at the bottom to scroll right and left on the entire page.

Comment: Are you using any external js/css libraries which are automatically aligning them on window resize? Otherwise window resizing will not affect your template's physical appearance.

Comment: @qwerty of course window resizing can affect the appearance of a page.  Even something as simple as some text in a div can be affected by window resize.  Where lines break, the height of the div, etc.

Comment: @JamesMontagne yes you are right. But I think it can be avoided by making divs and tables of fixed height/width.

Answer (score 0):

You can set width and height of the  styles and they will stay the same size.

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px;">
```

Or you can use CSS to set the style.